# Sending binary through HTTP with React-Native Fetch API

Tags: http, react-native, request, http-headers, fetch

Is there a way to use the Fetch API to upload a binary file (for instance to S3 using a signed URL) ?

That would be a simple PUT for some 'application/octet-stream'.

The XHR library is working, but I believe Fetch is better, especially in a React-Native environment.
Does React-Native Fetch support `Blob` nowadays?

Ideally I would like to do something like this, but `Blob` is undefined:

```
fetch('https://s3.amazonaws.com/signedUrl/', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  },
  body: Blob(filePath)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on Android/iOS and simulators, if you have the file system path to your binary, such as an image using the built-in `XMLHttpRequest` to send requests:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', serviceUrl);
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    } else {
      reject(xhr.response);
    }
  }
};

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');

xhr.send({ uri: 'pathToFile', type: 'image/jpeg', name: 'file' });
```

A sample **pathToFile** on macOS is *file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/061D4A47-6363-4996-A157-03E6AD2DD9E4/data/Containers/Data/Application/3900F3EF-3259-43CF-9400-87B638EF9A1B/Library/Caches/Camera/F86E7345-080A-4D51-A80E-0CAD3370A353.jpg*

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend to use: https://github.com/github/fetch as polyfill for Fetch since is not widely supported.

Fetch documentation sample:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

var data = new FormData()
data.append('file', input.files[0])
data.append('user', 'hubot')

fetch('/avatars', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```

I am using it as follows:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

function upload(e) {
  const file = input.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (e) => { 
    fetch('/avatars', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: e.currentTarget.result
    })
  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

input.addEventListener('change', upload, false)
```

Comment: React Native is related to mobile development, not web. There's no `input[type="file"]` on mobile device, just plain `XMLHttpRequest` object is used to send requests.